# How to spawn items in a chest after a player dies in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an adventure map where the player re-spawns inside a house when he dies. I'm relatively new to Minecraft, and I've just begun to fiddle with the command block.

What I would like to know: How can I spawn a specific list of items back into a chest after a player is killed?

I already know it can be done, I just haven't figured out how.

Also, is there a way to re-spawn a player's inventory back into a chest?

I used the anvil and renamed the objects I want to put back in the chest, and if the player dies it would be really awesome if the objects could just pop back into the chest inside the player's house.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an option to leave items in a player's inventory on death...

Comment: @BlaXpirit There is, but there may be extra items that the asker may not want the player to keep, for whatever reason. If that's not the case however, then `/keepinventory true` would at least be a temporary fix until the desired solution is found, or possibly a better fix as the user might not notice/look in the chest.

Comment: @LLF `/gamerule keepInventory true`

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to do this. First, you can do `/gamerule keepinventory true`, OR, when the player dies, you can spawn specific items in a chest. But that requires much more work. First, make a team using `/scoreboard teams add <teamname>` and then have the map put the player into the team with `/scoreboard teams join <@a,@p,@r,playername>`. That creates a team. Now you need to create an objective to track the number of deaths. This can be done by the `/scoreboard objectives add <name> <criteria> [internalname (optional)]` in this case, you would do `/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount`. But how will we know when to put items into the chest? Well, you would want a hopper clock (Search on google if you need more info on it) connected to a command block with a test-for to see whether a player has died: `/testfor @p[score_Deaths=1,score_Deaths_min=1]`
The output of the comparator next to it would connect to two command blocks. One with the command `/scoreboard players set @a Deaths 0` which has a four tick delay of a repeater. In the other, we will summon a chest with contents into it. This part is the most difficult, because you mustn't only summon the chest, but fill it with items/blocks. This will be the command you will (likely) use:

`/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:chest 1 replace {Items:[{id:<itemid>,Count:<amount>,Slot:<slotnumber>},{<repeatstepsforlastbracesformoreitems>}]}`

For example:

`/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 minecraft:chest 1 replace {Items:[{id:diamond,Count:1,Slot:0},{id:iron_ingot,Count:16,Slot:1}]}` would spawn a chest facing South above the command block with a diamond in the top-left-most slot, and would have 16 iron ingots right next to it. Learning how to use command blocks can be very frustrating, and can become time consuming, especially if you are making a CTF or Team Deathmatch map. Adventure maps are slightly more difficult, only because you will likely spawn a boss, with modified attributes. Also, you want to keep your redstone VERY organized, or it will be difficult to modify (Learned that the hard way...)

Note that chests will face SOUTH when it is spawned, and is recommended a chest is already in the coordinates so that it doesn't look like it magically appeared (Unless you want it to look like that). The command block with that MASSIVE command is activated with a one tick repeater. Please let me know if this was NOT what you were looking for, or if it didn't work! =)

### More Questions From Rave

#### To answer a few more questions, Here is the best way for a hopper clock:

1. Put a hopper down
2. Place a hopper facing the other one (Sneak + Click)
3. Break hopper facing ground
4. Place a hopper facing the other hopper, so the two chutes are connected
5. Put a comparator next to it
6. Put a repeater with a 1 tick delay at the end of the comparator
7. Toss an item into one of the hoppers, you will notice it begins to work

[image: Hopper Clock on Make A Gif]

#### And how to fix comparators giving out a weak signal with `/testfor`:

1. Make sure it isn't in "Subtraction Mode" (Not sure what it does exactly...) (Torch should be off when not powered)
2. Place a 1 tick repeater next to it

#### How to look at the coordinates of a block:

1. Press F3 (Some computers have a binding like mine, Fn + F3)
2. Look for:

- x:129.28349208(***129***)
- y:***56***(57.28382 eyes)
- z:293.138842(***293***)

3. In this case, x:129, y:56, and z:293

Comment: Nice answer, great detail.

Comment: ok, so another question then. I have everything set up except the hooper clock. Can't really find anything good on those. How would you set one up? (to be connected to the command block?)

Comment: sorry, hopper clock. yeesh. ;)

Comment: Ok, one more question. So I have the testfor setup, but the redstone right in front of the comparator is always on, but none of the rest of the redstone is. Why is that?

Comment: & it keeps saying "Found Rave185"

Comment: @Rave185 It will say that because it saw that you died, and registered the output. I also added new instructions under "More Questions From Rave" to fix those very minor problems (At least I think that's what they are...)!

Comment: Wait... ALWAYS on? After you **died**, and the signal couldn't end the `/testfor`, or its always on no-matter what?

Comment: I also added this handy little .gif file of a hopper clock, so its easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for the gif of the hopper clock. Yeah, I didn't have the repeater in the clock before, going to add that in now, but what I have is this:

Comment: 2 hoppers together, then going out to a comparator, to a repeater, then to another command block with the testfor function. The test for function, whenever the clock is on, always posts in the code found @Rave185. It then is supposed to turn on the comparator right next to it, but it doesn't. Don't know why... And actually, it only did the Rave185 when I had two equal signs in the Death equation. Now it's not ever doing anything... When I place a pressure plate where the command block should be, it works...

Comment: and one more addon, if I do ~0 ~1 ~0 as the coordinate for the chest, the command block just makes a chest right above itself, which works perfectly cause then I just have to turn the ~1 to ~2 to get it over a wood block.

Comment: Huh... I will look into that. You have to have it with one `=` because from what I understand it assigns something (This case, a redstone signal) and two `==` just checks for a true false (Again, that's what its like in programming and how I interpreted it). So try this: `/testfor @p[team=<teamname>score_Deaths=1,score_Deaths_min=1]` It said it found you. Which is perfect. I only forgot one thing. Why would you make a team to not use it? This ***should*** fix that problem

Comment: And the `~` that go in front of the coordinates that I used were relative. They are based on the position of the command block. Commands without the `~` are exact, and do not rely on the position of the command block.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I knew about those ~ before, had just fogotte nabout them. Anyway, yeah, i I have two equal signs in the testfor equation it just keeps popping up saying found Rave185 even when I haven't died! But I added something else in that I think fixed it... not the Rave185, but the one redstone qworking and the rest not. just added a repeater...

Comment: That's odd... I will look into it a little tomorrow!